# Почему не выводятся строки из базы данных (простой поиск строк в бд на странице сайта)?

Tags: php, sql

Есть форма поиска: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть база данных: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть код поиска по базе и вывод найденных строк. 
**Но при поиске страница просто перезагружается и результаты не выводятся.
Скажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?**

мне кажется, что в цикле while, но я не могу его понять.

Код index.php

```
<?php
// Хостинг
$sql_ipmysql = "localhost";
// Логин
$sql_login = "root";
// Пароль
$sql_password = "";
// База Данных
$sql_database = "base";

// Подключаемся к БД
$conn = new mysqli($sql_ipmysql, $sql_login, $sql_password, $sql_database);

if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    echo "Извините, возникла проблема на сайте";
    exit;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

<!-- Форма поиска по базе -->    
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон"/><br />
    <input type="text" name="dateadd" placeholder="Дата"/><br />
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя"/><br />
    <input type="text" name="place" placeholder="Площадка"/><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Поиск" />
</form>


<?php

if (isset($_POST['phone'])){
$zapros1 = " and 'phone' IN ('".$_POST['phone']."')";
} else {$zapros1="";}

if (isset($_POST['dateadd'])){
$zapros2 = " and 'dateadd' IN ('".$_POST['dateadd']."')";
} else {$zapros2="";}

if (isset($_POST['name'])){
$zapros3 = " and 'name' IN ('".$_POST['name']."')";
} else {$zapros3="";}

if (isset($_POST['place'])){
$zapros4 = " and 'place' IN ('".$_POST['place']."')";
} else {$zapros4="";}

$foolzapros="WHERE ".$zapros1.$zapros2.$zapros3.$zapros4;

//делаем запрос в базу данных
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `items` 
$foolzapros
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
";
if (!$result = $conn->query($sql)) {
    echo "Извините, возникла проблема в работе сайта.";
    exit;
}

while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$text=strtolower($data['name']);  
$text = preg_replace('%[^a-zа-я\d]%i', ' ', $text);
$text=str_replace ('   ',' ',$text);
$text=str_replace ('  ',' ',$text);
$text=str_replace (' ','_',$text);

} echo "

<p>
".$data['phone'].".".$data['dateadd'].".".$data['name'].".".$data['place']."
</p>
"

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Как то странно все выглядит. вы набираете какие то значения из БД в переменную $text, но ее потом нигде не используете и на сайт не выводите. Зато выводите несколько полей из $data, но уже после цикла, когда в $data уже ничего нет

Comment: И совет: _никогда_ не подставляйте значения переменных непосредственно в текст запроса, особенно если получили эти переменные от пользователя. вас взломают. _Всегда_ используйте подготавливаемые выражения и привязку значений. http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Это будет отдельная бд с простыми текстовыми значениями.

Comment: Ну какие нибудь echo должны быть внутри цикла ... и эти echo как раз должны использовать что то из $data. Судя по тому что вы скопировали тут использовался другой прием, весь выводимый текст накапливали в переменной $text и видимо подразумевалось что после цикла эту самую переменную надо вывести пользователю

Comment: внутри цикла для начала сделайте `while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) { echo 'name: '.$data['name']; }` и посмотрите что вышло. Ну а дальше уже экспериментируйте и выводите то, что вам действительно нужно

Comment: ничего не выводится. извиняюсь, что озадачил

Comment: тогда выведите сам sql-запрос прямо перед выполнением и выполните его сами в консоли mysql, убедитесь, что он действительно находит то, что вы ожидаете

Answer (score 0):

В вашем запросе после WHERE сразу идет AND [SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE and `phone` IN ...]. Пофиксите это и тогда должно будет работать.

Comment: Не помогло, страница просто перезагружается. Из первого запроса убрал END, получилось так 
$zapros1 = "'phone' IN ('".$_POST['phone']."')";   спасибо за участие!